# Hand gesture recognition based CAPTCHA

Tags: web-services, opencv, captcha, gesture, gesture-recognition

I am planning to make a Hand Gesture recognition based CAPTCHA. My idea is to implement captcha as something which asks user to make gestures as indicated on the screen(which will be images of the required hand gestures , like V, F, 2, etc with hand) and using pattern matching the system authenticates the pattern and directs to the next page if authenticated.

Now I am unable to decide how to make the UI and how can I incorporate this into a webpage(like a plugin or something). As of now I have been coding the same using visual studio and c++ using OPENCV library.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this library called "JSFeat", it implements basic computer vision algorithms in a web-framework that I could see you using to at least prototype your project:

http://inspirit.github.io/jsfeat/#imgproc

The demos opened up my webcam in the browser and ran some standard algorithms (edge detect, optical flow, etc). If you're developing your own algorithms, there's some matrix math to help out, though I bet you could also combine this with other javascript linear algebra libraries.

Best of luck.